# Use helper method in JSON with RABL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I have a simple `index.json.rabl` file with the following content:

```
collection @calls

attributes :time, :destination, :source, :duration
```

I also have a helper method which replaces the `source` value with a company name:

```
  def format_destination(destination_number)
    case destination_number
    when "12345
      "Name One"
    when "67891"
      "Name Two"
    else
      destination_number
    end
  end
```

Is it possible to replace the `:source` attribute in the RABL file with the helper method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using `node`:

```
collection @calls
attributes :time, :destination, :duration
node(:source) { |call| format_destination(call.source) }
```